Best Practices for Anonymous Crypto Payment System with User Tracking and Minimal Gas Fees?
I'm looking to implement a crypto payment system where users can deposit funds without logging in—ideally through a simple QR code scan or by pasting a wallet address. However, I still need a way to track each user and monitor their total deposits. The main requirements are:

Users deposit anonymously without requiring login.
The system needs to associate each deposit with a specific user ID for tracking purposes.
I want to know how much each user has deposited over time.
Ideally, I’d like to minimize gas fees and avoid dust deposits.

Questions:

Has anyone implemented a similar system or found ways to make anonymous deposits work while tracking users reliably?
When scanning the QR code in MetaMask, the metadata field appears empty. Has anyone encountered this issue, and is there a workaround to pass data reliably with the QR code?
Would using smart contracts be feasible in this context? If so, how could I reduce gas fees and avoid creating dust amounts?
Alternatively, is there a way to generate unique deposit addresses for each user and avoid dust completely?


This question is off topic, as it is not really related to cryptography. Consider asking elsewhere.

Requirement "Users deposit anonymously" seems to go very much against "I want to know how much each user has deposited over time".

It is a good idea, but there are many similar systems available, such as BitPay, CoinGate, etc. but if I want to answer your question, it is possible to identify users without registration, but not this one.
If you expect that you don't want to save any user information, but have access to some of its most important information, which is controversial, you can instead use Google login and define at least one ID for each user. You can also do it with the help of Firebase, which is easy to connect with Gmail to Firedata, and it is better to add some default information of the user that is sent with the header of his request, such as the IP and its location + the email that is connected with each other.
Do it in Json format and finally code the obtained result by base64 or cipher and save the code in your database so that if you want to check user information, you can access at least 40% of its information by its ID.
To change gas fee: you can change it with any library you use in your system's programming language, you can even set it to 0, but you must check if the desired transaction is published (confirmed).
For transmission, it varies in different networks and depends on the load of the network at that time, but most networks do not value transactions that have less gas and most of them are not approved or it takes hours to be approved.
Regarding the unique address, I suggest you convert the same user ID to hex and use it to ensure its security.

